# How to create a new document in Alfresco via REST API?

Tags: alfresco

How to create a certain type of document in Alfresco with using the Rest API. I would like to receive the URL to which to send the request and the list of required parameters. Tried to use http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Create_folder_or_document_.28createDocument.2C_createFolder.29 but it did not work out, because it could not determine which parameters to send to this API

Comment: Which Alfresco version do you use? 
Do you want to use CMIS or Alfresco's internal REST API?
Which type should your document have, do you have a custom content model?
Where do you want to create your document?

Comment: I use a version of Alfresco 4.2.c. I want to use the internal REST API, the document must be of type nid_employeeType, Model created by me, the document must be created in the folder with the name Organizations of the document library in a site named Jazz

Comment: do you want to create a document or upload a document?

Comment: I want create new document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links to get started with Alfresco + CMIS - These should help to solve your question in general: https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/cmis-resources-tutorials-and-examples-03212012-1456

Answer (score 1):

Would use the Rest API, not CIMS

```
import json
import requests
import os, sys

strUrl = 'http://your.site.com:8080/alfresco/service/api/'
strAuth = ('username', 'password')
strFilename = "somethingtoupload.pdf"
objFile= {'filedata' : open(strFilename,'rb')}
strData={'siteid': 'site','containerid': 'documentlibrary', 'uploaddirectory': 'somefolder'}

result = requests.post (strUrl+'upload',files=objFile,data=strData,auth=strAuth)
print result.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your owen webscript REST and personnalize your processing as you like or you can use this webscript "/api/upload".

Answer (score 0):

To create a document you need to use a query of cmis family. The query looks like:

```
nodeRef = b544cd67-e839-4c60-a616-9605fa2affb7;
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
     '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/"
xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">' +
       '<title>name</title>' +
       '<summary>name</summary>' +
       '<cmisra:object>' +
       '<cmis:properties>' +
       '<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">' +
       '<cmis:value>type</cmis:value>' +
       '</cmis:propertyId>' +
       '</cmis:properties>' +
       '</cmisra:object>' +
       '</entry>';

    url: "/../alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/" + nodeRef + "/children",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml;type=entry"
    },
xml:xml
```

name - document name;

type - document type;

nodeRef - folder id in Alfresco.

To create a document in type specify cmis:document. Other queries you can find here:

http://jazzteam.org/en/technical-articles/list-of-alfresco-services/

Answer (score 0):

def post():

```
    cms_repo_url = current_app.config.get("CMS_REPO_URL") 
    cms_repo_username =current_app.config.get("CMS_REPO_USERNAME")  
    cms_repo_password =current_app.config.get("CMS_REPO_PASSWORD") 
    if cms_repo_url is None:
        return {
            "message": "CMS Repo Url is not configured"
        }, HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

   
    if "upload" not in request.files:
        return {"message": "No upload files in the request"}, HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST

    contentfile = request.files["upload"]
    filename = contentfile.filename
    files = {'filedata': contentfile.read()}
    if filename != "":
        try:
            url = cms_repo_url + "1/nodes/-root-/children"
            document = requests.post(
                url,data = request.form,files= files,auth=HTTPBasicAuth(cms_repo_username, cms_repo_password)
            )
            return (
                (
                   
                ),
                HTTPStatus.OK,
            )
        except UpdateConflictException:
            return {
                "message": "The uploaded file already existing in the repository"
            }, HTTPStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    else:
        return {"message": "No upload files in the request"}, HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).